# How do I replace a string with a constant reference in Flex using getStyle?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I want to replace `getStyle('someStyle')` in mxml with

```
private static const SOMESTYLE:String = "someStyle";
[..]
<mx:Image source="{getStyle(SOMESTYLE)}" />
```

where someStyle is defined in my CSS.

This compiles, but gives me error on runtime: Error #1069: Property SOMESTYLE not found on package.class and there is no default value.

What is the appropriate way to reference to the class constant from the mxml?

edit: I'm using Flex 4.6. This worked just fine in Flex 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables or methods exist on the class; not on an instance of the class.  So you have to reference them using the class name; not the instance name.  You did not specify the class name in your code.

```
<mx:Image source="{getStyle(ClassName.SOMESTYLE)}" />
```

---

Here is some code that shows accessing a static constant inside the same class that defines it.  This file is named StaticVariablesInSameClass_SO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";


        s|Application{
            someStyle : 'https://www.flextras.com/Assets/images/flextras_logo3.gif';
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            private static const SOMESTYLE:String = "someStyle";

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace(this.getStyle('someStyle'));
                trace(this.getStyle(StaticVariablesInSameClass_SO.SOMESTYLE));
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Great answer! I'll just add, that the constant should be public

Comment: Actually made a lot of sense, however, I get an error in compilation: [module] SetupUtil.as: Access of undefined property ClassName. Does this occur because I want to define the constant in the same class as my mxml?

Comment: You'll have to replace ClassName with the actual name of the class.  And as @TimofeiDavydik said; I'd make sure that the static variable is public; not private

Comment: Just to make it clear; this didn't work when I had the constant in the same class as my mxml, it caused the error I described above. However, moving the constant to another class did the trick. I'm guessing it has something to do with static vs. non-static context. Yes, I made the constant public and also swapped classname with the correct name.

Comment: I added a code sample demonstrating how to access a static variable within the same class that defines it.  @TimofeiDavydik I guess it doesn't have to be public.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the initial help and followup :)